# Gnome equivalents of Openbox <application> section

Tags: gnome, openbox, gsettings

I need to configure windows geometry, but the session has no root privileges, meaning `openbox` cannot be installed, so only core commands are allowed to modify the properties of its `Gnome 3.4.1`. How can the windows system be configure with `gsettings` as to locate those windows of a certain name in the right half of the screen?